# Why we need a comma after variables in sqlite SELECT statement?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

i'm just asking why we use a ',' after our variable when we build a query with sqlite.

I couldn't fine any answer and explication about it. I just saw some people helping for other problem and using this comma.

Thanks by advance.

```
def search_by_title(title):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("lite.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM BOOKSTORE WHERE title=?", (title,))
    row = cur.fetchone()
    conn.close()
    return row
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your variable has to be the type [`tuple`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples.asp). The `execute` command needs a sequence as a parameter. You need that comma to create a `tuple`. 
Otherwise, it returns an object of the same type as the expression inside the parenthesis (for example `str` if you pass an `str` object - as you can see in my first example).

```
print(type(("Command")))
>> <class 'str'>

print(type(("Command", )))
>> <class 'tuple'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `cursor.execute()` expects the arguments for the query to be in a `tuple`. To have a one variable tuple you need to add a comma after the variable.

```py
title = "string"
var = (title)   # a string
var = (title,)  # a tuple with one string element
```